# Compute $\mathrm{Aut}(S)$ of the ring $S=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory

This problem once again is from a previous exam.

The problem is to compute the group of automorphisms of the ring $S$ where $S=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$

My thoughts: Well $x^2$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ so I am completely stuck.
Also what exactly is the theory I need to know to solve this problem?. I don't even
know where to look in the text book to find the relevant theory for this. In particular  I have not learned Galois Theory. In fact we don't need to know
Galois' theory for my exam. So I'm hoping this doesn't use any of that heavy machinery.

Can you guys help?

Thanks for your help and answers.

Comment: The problem definitely does not require Galois theory, or much field theory at all, really.  However if you do know some field theory the result may surprise you, since this is a case where the automorphism group of a finite-dimensional algebra turns out to be infinite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly anything in your ring can be written as $a + bx$ with $a,b \in \Bbb{Q}$ and $x$ subject to the relation $x^2 =0$. We also note that this ring is a finite (2 - dimensional) $\Bbb{Q}$ - vector space. Any endomorphism of this ring must thus be the identity on the rationals and so is completely determined by where you send $x$  and you could send it to any element $c + dx$ of the quotient. To given an automorphism, it thus is enough to give an ***surjective*** endomorphism of $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$ by rank - nullity.

For this necessarily we need to send $x \mapsto c + dx$ with $d \neq 0$ otherwise you will not hit those terms in $x$. Also as Jyrki rightly points out, if $\varphi$ is an automorphism of the ring, we need $\varphi(x)^2 = \varphi(x^2) = 0$ because $x^2 = 0$. In other words, $( c+dx)^2 = 0$ so that $c = 0$. So to summarize $x$ must be sent to $dx$ with $d \neq 0$ so that the automorphism group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}^\ast$.

Comment: Thank you. A couple of questions though. Why is this ring $2$ dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space?. And How does rank nullity apply here?. I am sorry if my questions are very elementary. But I am trying very hard to learn before the test :)

Comment: Benjalim: As @Jyrki says, your answer is not correct.  You need to send $x$ to an element which is not $0$ but has square $0$.  This means that you need $c = 0$ and $d \neq 0$.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Dear Pete, thanks for pointing out the mistake in my answer above. I have edited my answer and I hope it is correct now.