# $F$ is a field, $n>1$ is it true that $\mathrm{Aut}(F[x]/(x^n))=F^{\times}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

My question is to ask for whether the following generalization of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437859/compute-mathrmauts-of-the-ring-s-mathbbqx-x2/437901#437901) is true or not. The mentioned problem says $A:=\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2)) \simeq 
\mathbb Q^{\times}$ by proving every $\phi \in A$ then $\phi(x)=dx$ for $d \ne 0$ where $x$ is the coset of $X$.
So a natural question comes up: is it true that $\mathrm{Aut}(F[x]/(x^n))=F^{\times}$
where $F$ is a filed and $n>1$?

For instance let $F=\Bbb Z  /p\Bbb Z $, $n=3$.
For a ring homomorphism $\sigma$ from
$F[X]/(X^{3})$ to itself,
let $\sigma (x)=a+bx+cx^{2}\ (a,b,c \in F)$.
We want to find a condition on $a,b,c$ so that $\sigma$ is an automorphism.
We need $0=\sigma(x^3)=\sigma(x)^3$, hence $a=0$. We also need $0\ne\sigma(x^2)=\sigma(x)^2$
, hence $b \ne 0$. As a result, $x$ must be sent to $bx+cx^2$ with $b \ne 0$.
Can we conclude that $\mathrm{Aut}(F[X]/(X^3)) \simeq 
F^{\times}$?

I'm glad to hear from you.

Comment: I suppose you want the $F$-automorphisms.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need $F$-automorphisms.

Comment: No, it's not true: for $n=3$ we have that $\varphi:K[X]/(X^3)\to K[X]/(X^3)$ defined by $\varphi(x)=x(a+bx)$ with $a\ne 0$ (here $x$ is the residue class of $X$ modulo $(X^3)$) is an automorphism. In fact, all automorphisms are of this form. (One can generalize this to $n\ge 3$.)